# Data validation event in gridview is different even before user input

Tags: c#, validation, datagridview

I have this issue with data validation using a datagridview, the problem is that i didn't change nothing i just clicked on the cell and i wanted to see what's the values i get. And the formatted value from the event is not the one i have in the cell... It's cropped. I compare both values at the end after doing the validation and decide weather or not highlight the row as modified, and with this not only the value is considered edited right from the begining, but the values are changed even without any user input...

any ideas why it's acting like this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insted of

```
oldValue = dgAgiExport.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value.ToString();
```

should be

```
oldValue = dgAgiExport.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].FormattedValue.ToString();
```

For some reason Value != Formatted value, and "e" argument doesn't have a value. Only solution i found is to compare the formatted values which will in most cases end up incorrectly for datetime...

Another way is to use a list cause the value is not formatted but that sucks for ef...